# time function in php

Tags: php, mysql

Somehow I managed to make the date work,

```
<td width="67"><font size="3"><b>*Date</b></td>
<td width="3">:</td>
<td width="168"><input name="adate" type="text" id="adate" maxlength="20" value="<?php  echo date("Y/m/d") . "<br />"; ?>">
```

how do I echo the time in this form:

```
  <td width="67"><font size="3"><b>*Time</b></td>
    <td width="3">:</td>
    <td width="168"><input name="adtime" type="text" id="adtime" maxlength="15">

    </td>
```

Comment: Stop whatever you're doing and go read about SQL injection. NOW.

Comment: Why do you assume they don't know about SQL injection? I don't see any SQL queries in the question..

Comment: Unless something very weird just happened, there was. My take is that he edited the question. It was a full `INSERT` query with lots and lots of $_POST variables directly sent into it.

Comment: The question looked totally different before... 
I was writing a two page essay on how bad the query was till I saw the question has changed.

From the preview:
Is there a code in php that could replace the manually inputted date in here: $sqlque="INSERT INTO t2 (HOSPNUM, ROOMNUM, ADATE, ADTIME, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, MIDNAME, CSTAT, AGE, BDAY, ADDRESS, …

Comment: fascinatingly, zneak's original comment got up-voted after the SQL was removed from the question...

Comment: The meta thread for this question is at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41226/comment-gets-appended-to-url-question-apparently-edited-with-no-trail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what format you want for the time.

the php [date() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) has a number of different ways of representing time.  If you just want HH:MM:SS you could do this:

```
<td width="168"><input name="adtime" type="text" id="adtime" maxlength="15" value="<?php  echo date("H:i:s") ?>">
```

Comment: the current time in here(Philippines)(UTC+08:00) Taipei is 9:04 Am, how do I get that time?Because I'm only seeing: 01:02:42 when I used your code, how about Am or Pm.

Answer (score 2):

simply use the date function but with hour/min/seconds output..

```
echo date('H:i:s');
```

[Date Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 1):

> My advice if your programming in PHP
>   **go with a framework** like CodeIgniter,
>   CakePHP or Zend. Just dont code from
>   scratch out of thin air unless you
>   actually need to.